# ANTLR mismatched token in simple grammar

Tags: antlr3, antlrworks

I am currently debugging my grammar in ANTLRworks, and reduced it far more than is reasonable to this:

```
grammar DebugInternalGrammar;


RULE_STRING :
    '"' (
        ('\\' .) |
        (~ (
            '\\' |
            '"'
        ))
    )* '"'
;
```

Which, when testing in the interpreter against the String

> "L"

just yields

> MismatchedTokenException(76!=34)

What does work is matching `""`, also reducing the grammar to:

```
grammar DebugInternalGrammar;


RULE_STRING :
    '"' (
        (~ (
            '\\' |
            '"'
        ))
    )* '"'
;
```

matches `"L"` (I assume this is what it means when the parse tree in ANTLRworks shows `<epsilon>` as leaf).

What is wrong here? This is not the part of the grammar which caused me trouble before, so I am scratching my head as to what the problem could be and what ANTLRworks is trying to tell me.

Comment: Does it also fail if you try to use it (i.e. outside ANTLRworks)? In the [ANTLR3 Java grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v3/blob/master/Java1.6/Java.g) the rule looks basically the same, I don't see anything wrong here.

Comment: Look at the token list to see which tokens the lexer found. That might give you a hint why there is a token mismatch.

Comment: @MikeLischke That sounds useful, but how do I do it? The interpreter only shows the parse tree.

Comment: You have that TokenStream instance which you feed to your parser. Use that to iterate over all tokens and print their text representation to the console